# How to Extract ALL Unique Values from one table's column to another table's column?

Tags: excel, excel-2019

I am having serious issues trying to understand absolute reference within TABLES. I do not want to use the =UNIQUE function as it causes #SPILL errors and I need the unique values in another table. Furthermore, the =UNIQUE function is unique to Office 365 and I work in an office where most of our employees use Office 2019, so I really cannot use the =UNIQUE function even if that was the only method.

I have used the IFERROR/INDEX/MATCH/COUNTIF formula to extract all unique values from a column by referencing the cells themselves before, but I cannot reference it properly when extracting from one table into another table. Since I have to extract ALL unique values from one table's column to another table's column, I cannot understand how I should reference these columns or cells.

To the problem, I have two tables (named "ORDER_IN" and "INV") in two separate sheets ("ORDER" and "INVENTORY" respectively). The first table (Table "ORDER_IN" in sheet "ORDER") contains an order history of fruits along with their quantity and date. The columns are: "Fruit Name", "Order QTY", and "Date". The second table (Table "INV" in sheet "INVENTORY") contains "Fruit Name" and "Total IN". The same fruit can be ordered at multiple quantities in multiple dates. I need the workbook to serve two functions:

1. Sometimes, a new fruit can be ordered; hence, when I add it that "Fruit Name" to my "ORDER_IN", I want it to be automatically added to my "INV" Table. This is what I need help with.
2. Henceforth, I want that entry in the "INV" Table to automatically sum all values in the "Order QTY" column from "ORDER_IN" table and return the value to its respective "TOTAL IN" column on the "INV" table. I know how to do this using SUMIF.

I have added the images of the tables below. Basically, for example, I want the entry "Mango" to appear only once in the "INV" table with (20+80+80=) 180 under "TOTAL IN".

Table "ORDER_IN" in Sheet "ORDER"

[image: "ORDER_IN" Table in Sheet "ORDER"]

Table "INV" in Sheet "INVENTORY"

[image: "INV" Table in Sheet "INVENTORY"]

Table "INV" in Sheet "INVENTORY" (Completed) [This is what I want, but automatically; below table was manually filled]

[image: Table "INV" in Sheet "INVENTORY" (Completed)]

Comment: I'm using it in an office where most people do not use Office 365 and the =UNIQUE function is not available in previous version of Office. That's one of the main reasons I'm also trying to use the:
{=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$B$15, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$2:D2, $B$3:$B$15), 0)),"")} formula mentioned in some other parts of the internet. But I simply cannot get it to fit with my tables due to absolute references, which I don't know how to use with tables.
[ https://www.listendata.com/2013/05/excel-3-ways-to-extract-unique-values.html <- Link where I found the formula]

Comment: Well, that's different then.  I based my comment on your statement _I do not want to use the =UNIQUE function as it causes #SPILL errors_.  You made no mention of (some) users not having access to those functions.

Comment: The answer to your problem might be to us [Structured references](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e)

Comment: You're right. I'll edit the main post as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally managed to find the answer after hours of asking people around:

Type in this formula the Sheet "INVENTORY" on the first row under the Column "Fruit Name":

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(ORDER_IN[[Fruit Name]:[Fruit Name]], MATCH(0,IF(ISBLANK(ORDER_IN[[Fruit Name]:[Fruit Name]]),1,COUNTIF($A$1:A1, ORDER_IN[[Fruit Name]:[Fruit Name]])), 0)),"")
```

Then use: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Then Drag the Formula to the rest of the cells and see magic happen every time you enter new unique entries in the "ORDER_IN" sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the Advanced Filter using the following steps;

- Go to the new sheet where  you want the unique values to be
- Click on the Data Tab
- Click on Advanced
  [image: Data Tab]

[image: Advance Filter]

- select "Copy to another location"
- click the arrow on the "List range:" and select the range from the sheet where you want to copy the unique values from
- click on the arrow on the "copy to:" and select the cell where you want to copy the unique values to
- Click Ok and you unique values will be populated